# Unusual kernel behaviour when outputting directly to text video memory

Tags: gcc, x86, kernel, screen, osdev

I am working on a basic kernel. I followed some online courses and started writing this from scratch. I am seeing unusual behavior while writing this kernel. I am writing the kernel in *C* and the bootloader in assembly. The source code is available [here](https://github.com/shubham1172/os-simple).

**The problem:**

While printing a `*const char*` I found 0 indexing results in some garbage values whereas the real string is only seen from index 1. I decided to stick to this hack and go on coding the kernel in the hopes I could fix this issue later.

When I began writing a routine for updating cursor location in the print routine I encountered another problem. I updated the code to use the cursor position as offset alongside the x-y coordinates that I was using before. To my surprise, the indexing now starts at 2 instead of 1.

```
/** print msg at (x,y) or cursor */
void print_at(const char* msg, int x, int y){
  unsigned char *video = (unsigned char *)VIDEO_ADDRESS;
  unsigned int offset = 0, i = 1; // i=1?
  // decide offset value
  if(x>=0||y>=0){
    // get offset from coordinates
    offset = get_offset(x,y);
  }else{
    // get cursor
    offset = get_cursor();
    i+=1; // i=2?
  }
  while(1){
        char c = msg[i];
        if(c==0){
          // end of string
          break;
        }else if(c=='\n'||(offset/(2*MAX_ROWS)==MAX_COLS)){
          // go to next line
          offset = get_offset((offset/(2*MAX_COLS)),MAX_COLS-1);
        }else{
          // print the character
          video[offset] = c;
          video[offset+1] = WHITE_ON_BLUE;
        }
        offset+=2;i++;
  }
  update_cursor(offset);
}
```

My *get_offset(int row, int col)* routine is behaving unusually. The normal calculation for offset should be `(row*MAX_COLS+col)*2`. However, this results in something like this:

[image]

If I make the formula as `(row*MAX_COLS+col)*2+1`, the print function is working correctly:

[image]

My Makefile is:

```
# Makefile for OS
# Note: $^ = all dependencies, $< = first dependency, $@ = target


# Generate list of sources using wildcards
C_SOURCES= $(wildcard drivers/*.c kernel/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard drivers/*.h kernel/*.h)

# List of objects to build
OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

all: os-image

# run
run: all
    qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=os-image

# debug mode
debug: all
    qemu-system-i386 -s -S -drive format=raw,file=os-image

# build
os-image: boot/boot_sect.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > os-image


kernel.bin: kernel/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

# Generic rule for compiling C code to an object file
# For simplicity , the C files depend on all header files .
%.o : %.c ${HEADERS}
    gcc -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

# Assemble the kernel_entry .
%.o : %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf64 -o $@

%.bin : %.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -o $@

clean :
    rm -rf *.bin *.dis *.o os-image
    rm -rf kernel/*.o boot/*.bin drivers/*.o
```

My colleagues haven't been able to identify the problem either. How do I start debugging it?

Comment: `How do I start debugging it?` - Try to output a single character at the left upper corner, thus you will get offset for that position. Output single character at the right upper corner, remember this offset too. Output single character at the beginning of the second row. Then run your code under GDB and check that calculated 'offset' is one as expected.

Comment: The offset calculation should be `(row * MAX_COLS + col) * 2` (don't add 1). Your primary problem here is that you compiled and assembled all this code as 64-bit but are running in 32-bit protected mode.The anomalies you're seeing are because 64-bit code doesn't execute properly in 32-bit protected mode.Try compiling with GCC using additional options `-m32 -fno-PIC` and add to the LD options `-melf_i386` and change the NASM flags you use from `-felf64` to `-felf32` . This would build all the code as 32-bit. Also change `print_at` so it is `unsigned int offset = 0, i = 0;` .`i=1` is incorrect.

Comment: @Tsyvarev :In this case stepping through code (at the source level) alone wouldn't work. You'd have to step through the assembly instructions and then realize that the instructions being executed are not quite the ones in the executable.The bytes being executed are correct, but their interpretation isn't. This is a rather tough one for a beginner to pick up on IMHO. In general though if basic screen output isn't working it is often a sign that code was generated for 64-bit code and as run in 32-bit protected mode.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: My bad compiling 32-bit code in 64-bit mode! Everything works as expected now! Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! I marked this one as a duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the fact that I need to compile 32-bit code delicately on a 64-bit system. I solved the problem by adding `-m32` and `-fno-PIC` flags to GCC, `-melf_i386` to LD, and changing `elf64` to `elf32` in NASM in my Makefile.